# SharePoint Users with no access permissions to site are briefly able to see site before getting "Access Denied" if they click the link

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We have a site where users are not granted access to until they are actively working on it/assigned to it. However they are all included on emails where a link to the site could be, and if a user not assigned to that site clicks the link, the site briefly shows up before they then receive the access denied.

How can I stop the site from displaying before the user is checked as there is sensitive data on the screen?

We have checked the user groups and roles and all appear to be in order

Comment: Based on your description, when users with no access visit a site collection, contents of this site collection are displayed and then cannot be acessed . Is it right?